# Can't resolve component vue file from my router file

Tags: vue.js, path

My components `vue` files are in `src/components/` while my `index.js` router file (whose content is down below) is in `src/router/`.

Why do I get *"Error: Can't resolve './components/App.vue'"* error?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp.vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';

import Router from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    name: 'SignUp',
    component: SignUp
  },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `index.js` is on `src/router/` and your components are in `src/components` they are not in the same folder. So, for correctly import, you must put `../` to reference one level down to `/src/`.

It would look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from '../components/App.vue';
import SignUp from '../components/SignUp.vue';
import Login from '../components/Login.vue';
```

Answer (score 2):

`./` doesn't have a special meaning other than current folder as a relative path; With a folder structure as:

```
|-src
  |-components
    |-App.vue
  |-router
    |-index.js
```

You could either use `../` which backup one level from the current path:

```
import App from '../components/App.vue';
```

Or use `@` which refers to the `src` folder:

```
import App from '@/components/App.vue';
```

Comment: Thanks but @Theus answered lightly before so I had to accept that answer...

Comment: Not a problem -